# All the [option]s have been expended

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) tag says in big letters do not use (I was going to use it for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944103/elegant-way-to-check-toint-or-toboolean) question about Scala's option class) Can we either burninate the tag cause it says we cannot use it or change the wiki (I don't have privileges to do so) to have it be about Scala's `Option` class?

Comment: You are aware that [tag:option] will be misused anyway, just as [tag:select]?

Comment: Then buuuuuuuurrrrrrrnnnn her.... I dont think it is needed for scala context

Comment: Is there another tag specifically for the Scala Option class? I don't know if it's required or not, but it might be helpful to disambiguate some of the uses of the plain option tag.

Comment: @BilltheLizard I just think there would be too much of a use

Comment: Why not [tag:scala-option]?

Comment: I'm not convinced that we need a "scala-option" tag, so I prefer burnination.

Comment: @S.L.Barth Well, we already have it anyway...

Comment: @Deduplicator Oops, should have checked before commenting... all the same, that's one more reason to burninate [tag:option]. The term is too generic to make it a tag synonym of [tag:scala-option].

Comment: @S.L.Barth Just take a look at all the tags containing "option".

Comment: What to do with all the questions that are not about Scala option but already tagged with [tag:option] (there are 1622 questions right now)? If you're planning to use this tag for Scala, there should be a major clean-up then.

Comment: Note that there is also a tag [tag:optional] with 3,319 questions: *Found in programming languages such as Haskell (`Maybe`), Scala and Rust (`Option`), Apple's Swift (`Optional<T>` or `T?`), Java (`Optional<T>`) or F# (`option`).*  This looks to be intended to cover the functional programming [optional](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/the-option-type/) concept in [scala](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.x/scala/Option.html) and elsewhere.  Perhaps it should be renamed to optional-value or something similar?

Comment: @dbc different discussion; https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/412162/tag-merge-maybe-option-type-and-optional-option-type

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine - oh look at that. If we are cleaning up [tag:option] then maybe we need to clarify the name of optional at the same time. There's clearly a demand for a tag that captures the optional concept of functional programming in a language-agnostic way. If we do burninate [tag:option] we will need to give retag guidance for questions about it, so would this be the right time to clarify the name of [tag:optional]? Its guidance is quite clear.

Comment: @dbc convention is to burn tags one at a time even if closely related; and the combined 5k questions between the two tags is more than the current burn team can do in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: fyi, there are 411 tags which say "Do Not Use".  (here's the [list](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1633147/tags-with-excerpts-that-say-do-not-use))

Comment: and about a thousand unprocessed requests, @ashleedawg :) We'll get to them eventually, I hope.

Answer (score 44):

There is no consistency at all in how this tag is used. It's used for everything from [the HTML element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72320726/changing-the-color-of-a-dropdown-in-javascript) to [specific Java classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73448045/is-there-some-sort-of-generic-bound-in-java) to [configuring IDEs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72345168/myeclipse-setting-project-facets-showup-no-libraries-are-available-for-current) to [VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71942307/vba-in-excel-text-box). Moreover, none of those uses are any more "correct" than any other use. This tag is highly ambiguous and adds no information whatsoever to the question. I say we burninate it.

Comment: And do not replace it with anything else.

Comment: Well, no, replace it with the appropriate tag where appropriate, like [tag:html-select] or [tag:scala-option].

Comment: @TylerH we don't have c++-arrays, why should we have scala-option?

Comment: @user253751 That's a conversation to have w/ the Scala community separately from this burnination, since the tag already exists. You can't equate it to another data type of another language because it may not refer to the same kind of thing.

Comment: Saying that "this tag adds no information whatsoever" is simply not true. If there is already another tag (like 'scala') than this tag adds a whole lot of information. The strength of using tags for sorting/filtering any objects lies especially in this possibility to combine tags. I see no reason why a single tag should be enough to describe a question. I understand and accept that on SO this is the rule (tags that can mean different things in different contexts shouldn't be used), but I strongly disagree that they don't add information.

Answer (score 22):

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- For questions about the maybe or optional types (some types just called option, such as Rust's `Option`), use [option-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option-type).
- Questions about Scala's `Option`, provided it's about Scala's optional type and not settings, can use [scala-option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scala-option). Whether or not this tag should be merged into [option-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option-type) or not is a separate discussion.
- For questions about the HTML tag, use [html-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select)

## Progress:

The [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=option),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boption%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boption%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boption%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boption%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=266719)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: Quite a few questions seem to use [option] in relation to command line options on specific tools. Should they be tagged with [command-line-arguments]?

Comment: @Artemis Sounds reasonable to me

Answer (score -18):

I think if [option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option) was burninated, the tag [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maybe) should represent (monadic) optional values in Java, Rust, Scala and other languages in addition to its current use for Haskell.

Comment: I completely disagree. [Maybe] is thoroughly ambiguous.

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine [Maybe] it is, [maybe] it isn't.

Comment: That there is already a tag [tag:optional] that seems to cover this: *Found in programming languages such as Haskell (`Maybe`), Scala and Rust (`Option`), Apple's Swift (`Optional<T>` or `T?`), Java (`Optional<T>`) or F# (`option`).*

Comment: @dbc right, than that should be used. i just found the [maybe] tag and thought it was the defacto standard, but it apparently isn't.