# Tag merge: [maybe] -> [option-type] and [optional] -> [option-type];

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request

Haskell has a type called [`Maybe`](https://wiki.haskell.org/Maybe). This is an [Option Type.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type) I've broadened the [option-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option-type) tag now such that it includes the Maybe type in Haskell. I suggest we make the following synonyms for [option-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option-type).

- [maybe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maybe) (as mentioned above)
- [optional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional) (which is just a badly named duplicate tag for [option-type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/option-type))

This is also how [Wikipedia documents it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Option_type)

Comment: Carly Rae would prefer to keep the tag [as is](https://youtu.be/fWNaR-rxAic).

Comment: If we really want to merge [maybe] into [option-type] then we may also think about merging [optional](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/optional) into [option-type]

Comment: @DanielWiddis: That's title worthy:  Merge me, [maybe]

Comment: @Lino upgrading question to include that too good catch.

Comment: @DanielWiddis I thought Carly Rae Jepsen's song was about the `?` operator in the expression `me?()` where `me` is either a function or `null`.

Comment: @ZoestandswithUkraine - I see that [tag:options] got synonymized to [tag:option-type] -- but the latter has only 18 questions while the former had 3,319.  Did something go wrong?

Comment: @dbc I thought it was strange it let me synonymize those. I'll do a merge, that should sort out the rest. I shouldn't really have been able to make those synonyms to begin with; [optional] is substantially larger than option-type. The system normally blocks those and requires a merge to bypass

Comment: Merging fixed it. All good now