# The [options] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

I am proposing that the [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) tag be burninated.  There are about 1945 questions with the tag.  Most of the top answerers have only answered one such question; a few have answered two.  One top asker has asked two questions; the rest have asked just one.

**1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?**

No. To use the tag's description as a testament to its ambiguity:

> Options are various choices or courses of action available to someone in a particular situation.

Such situations will be dependent on a number of factors, such as language, runtime, operating system, security operations, etc. Options within different ecosystems might make sense but not a catch-all [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) tag. It only adds ambiguity, not clarity, to a question it's tagged with.

There are questions about `getopt` tagged with [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) as well as questions about using `git` command line options, etc. I can provide examples but these are fairly easy to search. In these cases the tags [getopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getopt) or [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git) suffice, there is no need for the [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) tag. So far I have not found any examples where [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) conveys any meaningful information to the post that is not provided by a different existing tag.

What "options" means to the asker is going to be context dependent based on the tools and environment available at the asker's disposal. It is ambiguous in every sense of the word.

**2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?**

Options are settings and aside from *implementing* options (which again is ambiguous since the context of implementation matters). Context-specific options tags may be on topic but not a catch-all [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) tag. It would be more appropriate to use a language, runtime, or program specific tag than [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options).

**3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?**

Not on its own. A more granular, context-specific tag may be useful but in its current form it only adds ambiguity.

**4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?**

No. Different options have different effects across different platforms, environments, frameworks, and runtimes. Options in one context may be invalid in another. Options have different definitions as well in other fields of study, such as finance.

Comment: See [Are we all out of \[Option\]s?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266719)

Comment: @Dharman [tag:option] is a distinct tag from [tag:options]. That request is also from 7 years ago.

Comment: [tag:option] and [tag:options] are problematic for very similar reasons, so the questions are certainly _related_ (though of course not duplicates).

Comment: Ah, my mistake. I took it as they were suggesting my request was a dupe of the [tag:option] request. They are related, I will agree there!

Comment: There are even questions tagged both [option and options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options+option)...

Comment: That is easy to fix by merging, @Adriaan. The hard part is cleaning up and disambiguating the resulting questions.

Comment: There are over 1900 questions with the [tag:option] (singular) tag.  Both the [tag:options] and [tag:option] tags should be burninated, but the sheer quantity of questions means that manual processing would be a pain — they really need to be done automatically.  I wonder if there are any questions with only the [tag:option] or [tag:options] tags (or both)?  Almost certainly not, so simply getting the tags removed automatically would be a help, especially if we can avoid bumping all the edited questions to the front page of Stack Overflow.

Comment: I don't think creating topic-specific options tags ([tag:filesystem-options], etc) is a good idea in general; the tags would have been created by now if they were desirable.  (In passing, there are precisely two questions with both the [tag:option] and [tag:options] tags.)

Comment: I didn't say those sub-tags have to be created, I said it may make sense in some cases. I went a little overzealous with the examples, but those should not be the main focus of this request.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler there are two questions with both tags:  https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boption%5D+and+%5Boptions%5D

Comment: I don't think it's a good argument to say, if it's a desirable tag it would exist by now.

Comment: Is the [option] tag in scope with this?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine I did not propose this as such since [tag:option] has a significant number of posts on its own. Practically speaking however, I think most of the arguments supporting burninating [tag:options] would additionally support the burn of [tag:option] as well.

Comment: That said, as [@Dharman](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417320/should-we-burninate-the-options-tag?noredirect=1#comment904065_417320) helpfully pointed out, there is a separate burn request for [tag:option].

Comment: We can do both at once if there's consensus to do so, but double burns are a bit of an edge-case and technically pushing it. Though the reality is that we'd synonymize option into options (for meta post consistency, not because plural is preferred), there isn't much support in doing  so. We'll do [option] in the near future instead, it's all good

Comment: @Bender That's why I'm not personally pushing for it. 4k in one burn that could be 2k is substantial, so the community _has_ to back the option for that to be on the table. This late in phase 2 though, it's unlikely to happen, and I'm gonna start the burn in a couple hours anyway (unless the discussion escalates by then; will allocate more time if needed, though I don't see that happening to be honest).

Comment: In either case, barring unforeseen events leaving me unable to follow through on this, burninations aren't going to stop any time soon. There will be breaks along the way (to avoid burnouts, on a scale of a couple weeks to a month at most), but not doing [option] now does not mean waiting 6-8, like it has in the past. The next two burninations (including a double one) are already mapped and planned, and account for around 1.2k questions total. I've lined up [option] after those. Assuming roughly average progression, that means [option] starts phase 2 in 2-3 weeks.

Comment: I came across a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727316/variant-options-on-shopify) (still) tagged with both [tag:variation] and [tag:variations].  Editing automatically removed the singular tag — it is a synonym for the plural tag.  It has no tag wiki information, 7 watchers (why?) and 462 questions.  It seems likely that should be converted into another burnination request.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler So write a meta post if one doesn't exist already

Comment: 0 open questions left.

Answer (score 25):

From the random sample I have selected, I conclude that there's absolutely no need to have this tag or replace it with any other tag with some small exceptions (see below). The majority of questions tagged with it should be edited and the tag removed. Some notable exceptions:

- If the question relates to HTML's `<option>` element, use [html-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select) and make sure to remove [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) also.
- If the question is about designing an option menu, use [optionmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optionmenu)
- If the question is about financial options, use <s>[stock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stock)</s> [trading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trading)
- If the question is about command line arguments, use [command-line-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line-arguments).  (If it's about command-line options for a program that's already named by another tag, the question may not need this tag.)
- If the question is about compiler options, use [compiler-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-options)

In all other cases, the tag should be removed as it is a meta tag that adds no useful information.

**See also the community-wiki answer with more detailed retag guidelines.**

Comment: Other relevant tags: [tag:optional] ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19765713/208273)), [tag:arguments] ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22026694/208273) - already has it in addition).

Comment: Technically, stock and options aren't the same thing. Maybe we should have a single tag for all financial instruments?

Comment: @EJoshuaS-StandwithUkraine they're both *securities*, a term that definitely would not get misused constantly if we made it a tag ;-)

Comment: Stock is also a rather bad tag so it might get burninated in future too. Do we really need to have a tag for financial securities?

Comment: Do programmers need to know what the api they are calling or what the numbers represent? No, then no. (I mean, they pull the same stunts [they do elsewhere because they don't review their code anyways](https://dougseven.com/2014/04/17/knightmare-a-devops-cautionary-tale/))

Comment: @RyanM Good point :)

Comment: @Dharman Might be worth another Meta post on whether or not people want a tag like that - I can see both sides of that particular issue. I don't think it really makes sense to use the [stock] tag to refer to both stocks and options (since they really aren't the same thing), but I don't think that we should create tags for every possible financial instrument either. I'd personally be in favor of either removing [stock] entirely or creating a new tag for all financial instruments.

Comment: If we are discussing whether or not to have a single securities tag for things like stocks and options trading, `financial-securities` or `securities-trading` should eliminate any confusion with other security-related topics. While you wouldn't be a programming expert for stocks or options on their own, you *can* be an expert in implementing trading software. We would probably want a dedicated discussion thread for this though, since I can also think of reasons not to have such a tag, and I'm sure I'm not the only one with counterpoints here.

Comment: @Bender are the topics that any of those tags describe even on topic for SO?

Comment: @Braim I can think of evidence for and against, which is why I suggested a dedicated thread to foster more detailed discussion on the matter.

Comment: Hmm, seems like we may need a tag for [`Microsoft.Extensions.Options`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Options/).  [First question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72645180/ioptionswritable-update-not-writing-to-json-file) I looked at is specifically about that.  Or is [tag:appsettings] enough?

Answer (score 12):

[options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- If the question relates to HTML's `<option>` element, use [html-select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/html-select) and make sure to remove [select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/select) also.
- If the question is about designing an option menu, use [optionmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optionmenu)
- If the question is about financial options, use [trading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/trading)
- If the question is about command line arguments, use [command-line-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/command-line-arguments)

  - For questions about the UNIX C header `getopt.h`, use [getopt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/getopt)
  - If the command line arguments are compiler options, use [compiler-options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/compiler-options)
  - For Java command line arguments (JVM Options) use [jvm-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jvm-arguments)
- For optional arguments/parameters use [optional-arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-arguments) or [optional-parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/optional-parameters) (consider [What's the difference between an argument and a parameter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/156767))
- Questions about settings in general may be tagged [settings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/settings), though more specific tags can and should be preferred when they exist.
- For questions about Android's menu XML resources, use [android-optionsmenu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-optionsmenu)
- For questions about the OPTIONS verb in REST API requests, use [http-options-method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http-options-method)

## Progress:

The [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=options),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boptions%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boptions%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boptions%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Boptions%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=417320)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit))

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: Not entirely sure whether recommending [tag:settings] is a good idea or not. It might be a burn candidate itself at some point. Hasn't been discussed explicitly so far though. /shrug, I don't really have a preference. Feel free to remove

Comment: Can you give guidance on tag [tag:optionmenu] vs [tag:options-menu], or is that a subject for another burnination request?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler those two tags are synonymized to the same tag ([optionmenu]), which in turn appears to be [android-optionsmenu]; will have to look closer when I get back on my computer, but I suspect this is synonym fuel, or a burnination

Comment: No, I'm wrong. Optionmenu is the generic component, the android variant is just a specific implementation of an option menu

Comment: Hm, I'm not a fan of options-menu in general either. Maybe rename it to [option-menu]?

Comment: Ah — I didn't spot that [tag:options-menu] was a synonym of [tag:optionmenu] (I'd typed "options-" and the hyphenated version popped up, but going to the tag links shows they are treated as the same thing).  I wonder why the non-hyphenated version was chosen as the definitive name; modern style would suggest that the hyphenated version is a better choice.  But that is all tangential to burninating [tag:options].

Comment: There is [tag:scala-option]. Just applied it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69259060/subtracting-two-optiondouble)