# The [variations] tag has been burninated

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

As I was working on the [burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/417320/the-options-tag-has-been-burninated) of the [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) tag, I came across the question [Variant options on Shopify](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28727316/variant-options-on-shopify) which had both the [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variation) and [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations) tag (as well as the [options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/options) tag).  When I edited the question, the singular [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variation) tag vanished — it is a synonym of [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations).  But the [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations) tag seems dubious to me.

---

#### Burnination Criteria

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

   Not really, and no, it is not unambiguous.
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

   Not really.
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

   Not really.
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

   No — but it seems to have some significance in relation to WooCommerce.

---

#### Statistics

Consider the statistics:

- It has no wiki entry
- It has 7 watchers (leaving one wondering why it is watched)
- It has 534 questions
- One user has answered 124 questions in the tag (and almost certainly those are mostly related to [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce)); another has answered 7; the next highest user has answered 2.
- One user has asked 3 questions; three users have asked 2 questions.

Of the 534 questions:

- 346 are also tagged [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce)
- 26 are also tagged [python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python) or [python-3.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python-3.x) (or both)
- 14 are tagged [php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php)
- 13 are tagged [r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/r)
- 10 are tagged [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript)
- At least 1 ([Lean Six Sigma Negative Variance Significance Factor (VSF)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69431590/lean-six-sigma-negative-variance-significance-factor-vsf)) has only the [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations) tag — I'm not sure what it should be tagged with.

---

#### Courses of Action

Originally, I thought the tag should be burninated because it doesn't really seem to add any information to many of the questions.

However, it appears to be associated with a part of WooCommerce. If it survives (and it seems that it probably should), then it should be associated with WooCommerce only — all other questions should lose the tag.  So, instead of being a full burninate request, this probably becomes a 'cleanup the tag' request:

1. Provide a tag wiki entry that clearly identifies that it is for use with WooCommerce only.
2. Remove the tag from the majority of the 188 questions tagged with [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations) and not tagged with [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) too.  Some may need the [woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce) tag added.

More controversially and less definitively, if it survives, maybe it should be renamed with a systematic prefix such as [woocommerce-variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce-variations).

What say you?

<sup>*[Enigma Variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enigma_Variations)*</sup>

Comment: I think a WooCommerce SME should say if "variations" is enough of a feature for it to have its own tag (450 Qs can make a useful grouping). In which case a rename and clean-up are the right choice.

Comment: *"One user has answered 124 questions in the tag"* ...mostly because they've been adding the tag to related questions that they answer, rather than because askers are finding the tag and using it on their questions.

Comment: @bad_coder I doubt such person could do a valid case, considering that the topic that represents the tag is already covered by woocommerce.

Comment: @RyanM The SME in question ranks at the top or near it for both the WooCommerce and WordPress tags, chances being the tag is useful for users who know how to search by tag. (Most tag SMEs have to refine the minor tags on less experienced users' questions more often than not. Like I say, it's speculative until someone with real subjective matter expertise gives their opinion.)

Comment: I was thinking of contacting the user who's answered many questions, but their profile indicates that they've not been seen for over a year, which makes it likely that any contact would have to be done outside SO (there are links in their profile).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler there are other active SMEs and if pinged in the comments they might give an opinion, however let's assume those 450 variation Qs are tagged right, do we want to risk unwinding what might have been a careful tagging? I think this request has merit both as a clean-up and burnination, but it might be better to hold-off for now considering there's no small amount of other burnination requests needing attention.

Comment: Here's some info on [Woocommerce Variations](https://woocommerce.com/document/variations-as-single-products-for-woocommerce/) which also appear to be called Product Variations or [Variable Product](https://woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/) for which there is a [`[variable-product]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-product) tag.

Comment: @bad_coder: As more information comes to light on the WooCommerce association, the more I think that rather than removing the tag altogether, the questions related to Woocommerce should keep the tag and those unrelated to Woocommerce should have the tag removed.  The Wiki entry for the tag should make this clear.  Not being an SME on WooCommerce/Variations, I would defer to others with a better informed view on renaming the tag, or on synonymizing it to another tag.

Comment: Synonymizing it to another tag will be helpful instead of removing

Comment: @DanielWiddis — FWIW: I've created a version of the tag wiki for [tag:product-variations], emphasizing that it should be used with the [tag:woocommerce] tag and not used unless that's appropriate.  It also cross-references this question.  I still am not an SME on WooCommerce — I've not touched it except perhaps as an end user on some websites — so I'm entirely happy if other people who are more nearly an SME improve what I've provided.  I've used material from your [comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/419441/the-variations-tag-has-been-burninated#comment919872_419441), Daniel.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- Questions about product variations in any e-commerce platforms can be tagged [product-variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product-variations) for now; see note below.

  - if the question includes both tags [product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product) [variation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variation) they should both be replaced with the hyphenated tag.
- Questions asking about the mathematical expression for variety in a dataset may be tagged [standard-deviation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/standard-deviation), **if and only if** it is an on-topic about programming. Pure math questions should be closed.
- Questions asking about variety in general probably do not need to have the tag replaced, unless it happens to correspond to a concrete product/library/tool/etc. Examples of applications that don't need a tag include data variation (except when asking about established mathematical expressions of variation, see previous point).
- DO NOT use [variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variant) as a retag target, unless the question is about the data type in OCaml, VB, C/C++ via [the Windows API.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/variant-structure) (and `_variant_t`, also via the Windows API), or potentially other languages. If [variant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variant) is observed on questions about anything but the data type, it should be removed.

### Related cleanup efforts

**TL;DR:** [variable-product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-product) is planned for a merge into [product-variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product-variations). The fate of [product-variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product-variations) from there cannot be determined from the discussion here. These tags are NOT part of the burnination, and should not be removed in their entirety. Normal cleanup is still needed.

---

As no SMEs appear to have chimed in, and all uses I'm seeing is of a very simple concept, a single unified tag for the concept now lets us have a proper discussion about the tag later, if someone decides that discussion is needed. Particularly, it doesn't seem a tag for the same thing for each e-commerce platform is needed. Plus, if separate tags are needed, CMs/devs can be roped in to split the tag with fancy database magic following a minor cleanup, as long as the questions going into it now are as correctly tagged as possible.

All mentions of variations I'm seeing on e-commerce questions is different implementations of being able to have several variants of a single product, such as size or color variations. This wouldn't be the first time we use tags for concepts implemented in several languages (or platforms, as is the case here); examples include numerous basic and custom (but still widely used) data types and logic statements (if statements, various loop constructs, functions, etc.).

Unless an SME objects at some point soon, this is what we're rolling with for now.

## Progress:

The [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions to improve the question *and* remove the tag (retag-only edits are best left to users with full edit privileges; i.e. > 2k reputation),
- **flagging/voting to close** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based (users with < 3k reputation can help quite a bit by flagging questions for closure, which helps keep the Close Vote Review Queue full),
- **filtering** for questions with this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=variations),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted semi-automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvariations%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvariations%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvariations%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bvariations%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Track the progress of burnination

- [Coordination chatroom](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244740/burnination-hq)
- [Progress tracker](https://rodgort.sobotics.org/progress?metaQuestionId=419441)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance". (Edits, specially re-tags, are best left to users with [full edit privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit).)

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/voted for closure. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations) tag—just flag/vote to close the question.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions which still have the [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: I'm trying the progress tracker link and not seeing any progress recorded (despite the fact that I've edited some questions hours ago so that they no longer have the [tag:variations] tag).  Am I somehow clicking on it wrong, or is it not working properly?

Comment: It picked up two tags that aren't being burned... I've corrected it now, but it won't show the full progress, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks — that's definitely better than what I was seeing.

Comment: There are no open questions left with the [tag:variations] tag.  Nor are there any closed questions with it.  I think the burnination is substantially complete.

Answer (score 11):

I think many of these questions are about the same thing in Woocommerce, so the best course of action may be to remove the [variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variations) tag from all the questions that aren't about Woocommerce, then rename the tag to [woocommerce-variable-products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/woocommerce-variable-products), which is what the concept is [called most prominently in the docs](https://woocommerce.com/document/variable-product/).

Additionally, we should merge in [product-variations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/product-variations) ([minimal cleanup needed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bproduct-variations%5D+-woocommerce+-%5Bwoocommerce%5D+is%3Aq&searchOn=3)) and [variable-product](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/variable-product) which seem to be the same.

Thoughts? I'm not an expert in Woocommerce, so I'm open to suggestions from those who are.

Comment: +1 on merging `product-variations` and `variable-product`.  But do we need a separate `woocommerce-variable-products` if we already have a `variable-product` tag and `woocommerce` tag?

Comment: @DanielWiddis What's the downside? The tag [variable-product] is currently only used for Woocommerce questions (except one question).

Comment: The downside is having two tags (woocommerce-variable-products and variable-product) for the same set of questions.  Just have one variable-product tag.

Comment: @DanielWiddis They would all get merged together and become the same tag, but with different aliases.

Comment: Ah, I get it now. Your answer isn't clear about which the final tag would be. I don't think it should be specific to woocommerce.

Comment: There is currently just one question ([How to create a product page with variant dropdown in React?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63335389/how-to-create-a-product-page-with-variant-dropdowns-in-react)) that has the [tag:variable-product] tag but does not also have the [tag:woocommerce] tag.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler but there are 13 questions that have `[product-variation]` and not `[woocommerce]`.  They include `[reactjs]` (like the one you cited), `[django]`, `[shopify]`, `[bigcommerce]`, and `[vue]`, as well as some programming-related non-branded combinatorics questions.  Woocommerce may have given it an official name, but the concept is not woocommerce-specific.

Comment: @DanielWiddis — at that point, I have to defer to SMEs.  I'm not an SME on the nuances of the tags — I only know that neither [tag:variations] nor [tag:variable-product] has a tag wiki (at least when I checked just now).  There is no guidance for the uninitiated (like me) on what's expected.  I am not even sure whether anyone has a coherent, explicable set of expectations.  And I'm not convinced that the various tags that are not WooCommerce warrant a tag for 'product variation'.  If it weren't for the predominance of WooCommerce, I'd be rooting for the complete removal of these tags.